# iOS 8 cocos2d image coordinates issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios8

I'm trying to update my cocos2d game for iOS 8 and getting issues.

My game with Xcode 6 GM, iPhone 5 simulator with iOs 7.0.3 was working fine but using iOS 8 simulator all images are shifted to 25% left and 25% top and I can't get correct coordinates. 
Please refer image for details
[image]

Any help appreciated
Cheers 
Jeet

Answer (score 3):

Set correct device orientation in target settings
[image: Device orientation settings]

Comment: Well, this settings helped me, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I changed my settings and it was working on my iPod Touch but not my iPod Mini. After changing the setting for both iPod and iPad it started working correctly on both :)

Answer (score 3):

I am having the exact same issue.  For me, I was able to "fix" it by simply selecting "Portrait" for device orientation (even though my app is landscape like yours).

I realize this isn't the cleanest fix and it might have unintended consequences, but, since I need to update my app asap (it crashes on iOS 8), I'm going with this solution for now.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This started some other crashing issue. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who have exactly the same problems, just use `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]` instead of using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size`
Also don't forget to add new launch images for iPhone6/+ in Xcode 6. You can use your iPhone 5/S launch image. In this case you don't need to make new image assets for iPhone 6/+ resolutions

Comment: Changing that is not having any effect in my case :(  window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; My window is still initialised this way. What to replace it with ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix, (put it portrait) and...

```
NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    [window setRootViewController:viewController]; //iOS 6
} else {
    [window addSubview: viewController.view]; //iOS 5 or less
}
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
viewController.view.transform = transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to fix it in my project check the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26362815/2448816