# iOS 8 autorotate rotates images off the screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios8

So I recently heard word from my customers about a strange issue.  The screen will go black on them when they try to rotate their screen.  This appears to be an iOS 8 thing only since my latest release was just to add iOS 8 to the mix.

From my viewcontroller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    //
    // There are 2 ways to support auto-rotation:
    //  - The OpenGL / cocos2d way
    //     - Faster, but doesn't rotate the UIKit objects
    //  - The ViewController way
    //    - A bit slower, but the UiKit objects are placed in the right place
    //

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    //
    // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    //
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by cocos2d
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscape mode
    //
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    } else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }

    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
    //
    // return YES for the supported orientations

    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );

#else
#error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION


    // Shold not happen
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

I was able to reproduce it on my device as well as the simulator....

Landscape Left
[image: Landscape Left]
Portrait
[image: Portrait]
Landscape Right
[image: Landscape Right]

From what I can tell based on this a similar iPad test, is that the image actually rotates itself off the screen.  I currently allow all 4 orientations even though the game is in landscape because I'm using game center and at least some older iOSes required portrait log ins.   I'm using a rather old version of cocos2d (v1.1.0-beta2b), but I've never experienced anything like this before.  I can probably just change the supported orientations and turn off auto rotate, but I would like to fix it.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got the issue with cocos1.0 as well when I compile for ios8. In my code I found that I did have a UIViewController that is used as the root view controller (its child is in the EAGLView used by Cocos2D).

The fix I found is to comment the following method from my UIViewController

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I've done quick test on ios8 and ios7, and it works

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was bashing my head against a wall as every iOS update breaks my old cocos2d app haha.